# How to take cell out of cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to this works out of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: what did you try? include attempts, results, circumstances! Expected and actual Output are of great help

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the cell by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with an `NSIndexPath` object with its `row` set to zero and then set the colour. In your `IBAction` method, do this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```